# Typescript + Google Maps API + infobox.js Uncaught TypeError: InfoBox is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, maps

Have a project Vue.js + Typescript using Google Maps API, try to import infobox.js (npm package google-maps-infobox-window) library into and getting an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: InfoBox is not a constructor

Library doesn't typed yet, so all is remains - import as any, without typings. I tried 3 ways to do it:

- import * as InfoBox 'google-maps-infobox-window'
- var InfoBox = require('google-maps-infobox-window')
- making *d.ts file with manual module/function declaration

And none of these actions has no effect, `InfoBox` constructor still not found.
Before import infobox.js I already has imported googlemaps (via script tag) and RichMarker.js (via require('')) and those are works perfectly.
Can anyone help with it?

Also, I tried to add `"allowJs": true` to tsconfig.json, still nothing

Code:

```
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';
const RichMarker = require('js-rich-marker');
//problems started below when I use
import { InfoBox } from 'google-maps-infobox-window';
// or this
const InfoBox = require('google-maps-infobox-window');

//...

//and try to use imported function (constructor)
let infoBox = new InfoBox({content: boxText});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In search of problem solution I tried a lot of possible ways and all npm packages related to infobox.js. 
Finally, I found 'google-maps-infobox' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-infobox), which has no exhaustive description, but it was working one at least. Moreover, it has even *.d.ts file, which provide proper import in ts-project.
So, I installed this dependency and added in import section of component

```
import InfoBox from 'google-maps-infobox';
```

and use it in this way

```
//in some method (function)
let infoBox: InfoBox = new InfoBox({
    content: //some html markup
});
infoBox.setPosition(mapObject.getPosition());
infoBox.open(this.map);
```

Also, this package works good with require() import, except of InfoBox-object will be typed as any